# Service layer doesn't capture the DAO/Repositary layers exceptions for DML Queries(Insert)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I use Spring + Hibernate JPA in my application to insert the record into the Database.

Controller --> Service --> DAO(Repository) --> DB

I have the service which has @Transactional annotated method and it call DAO method to insert the record into the DB. When there is a duplicate record insertion , I see the DataIntegrityViolation is caught by Controller not by Service.

Please help to find why exception during DB process is not caught inside service layer though the method has all the exceptions inside try-catch block.

When I debugged the service I could find that commit is happening only at the end of service method call. [Please find the logs that explains that the commit is happening only after the end of Service method call inside controller].

I want to know why is the commit is not happening within @Transactional annotated method at Service layer.

My Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getTestData() {

       try {

       } catch(MyDefinedException e) {

       } catch(Exception e)
             // DataIntegrityViolation is caught only in this block
             LOGGER.error("Exception caught in controller"+e);
       }        
       return mv;
     }
 }
```

My Service implemetation :

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService  {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public String myServiceMethod(Object obj) throws myDefinedException {
          LOGGER.debug("----Entering into service method----");
          MyTableEntity myTableEntity = obj;
          try {
                   myDao.myDaoMethod(myTableEntity);
          } catch (EntityExistsException ee) {
               LOGGER.error("ServiceEntityExistsException caught"+ee,ee);
               throw MyDefinedException("ServiceEntityExistsException caught", new Exception(ee));
          } catch(PersistenceException pe) {
               LOGGER.error("Service PersistenceException caugth"+pe, pe);
               throw MyDefinedException("PersistenceException caught", new Exception(pe));
          } catch(ConstraintViolationException e1) {
               LOGGER.error("ConstraintViolationException caught"+e1, e1);
              throw MyDefinedException("ConstraintViolationException caught", new Exception(e1));
          } catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
              LOGGER.error("Service IllegalArgumentException caugtht"+iae, iae);
              throw MyDefinedException("IllegalArgumentException caught", new Exception(iae));
          }  catch(DataIntegrityViolationException dive) {
              LOGGER.debug("Service DataIntegrityViolationException caugth"+dive); 
              throw MyDefinedException("DataIntegrityViolationException caught", new Exception(dive));          
          } catch(JDBCConnectionException ex) {
              LOGGER.error("Service JDBCConnectionException caught"+ex, ex);
              throw MyDefinedException("JDBCConnectionException caught", new Exception(ex));
          } catch(DataAccessResourceFailureException darfe) {
              LOGGER.error("Service DataAccessResourceFailureException caught"+darfe, darfe);
              throw MyDefinedException("DataAccessResourceFailureException caught", new Exception(darfe));
          } catch(Exception e) {
              LOGGER.error("Exception caught"+e, e);
              throw MyDefinedException("Exception caught", new Exception(e));
          }
    }
    LOGGER.debug("----Leaving from service method----");
    return "success";
}
```

MyDao :

My DAO/Repositary implemetation :

```
@Repositary
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MYSCHEMA")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public String myDaoMethod(MyTableEntity myTableEntity) {
       LOGGER.debug("----Entering into DAO method----");
       entityManager.persist(myTableEntity);
       LOGGER.debug("----Leaving from DAO method----");
    }
}
```

Log :
I could find via log that the commit is happending only at the end of Service method call

```
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.197 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.203 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.s.internal.StatisticsInitiator - Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.205 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Opened session at timestamp: 15477476831
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.212 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Setting flush mode to: AUTO
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.213 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.213 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@9d02de] for JPA transaction
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.216 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.450 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.r.j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor - Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.450 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.r.j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor - Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.450 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterBeginCallback
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.452 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect
$HibernateConnectionHandle@80326e]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.452 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6efafe] for key [org.apach
e.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@157d1a0] to thread [qtp10408676-64]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.452 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@fc93a7] for key [org.springfram
ework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@41b972] to thread [qtp10408676-64]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.453 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Initializing transaction synchronization
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.453 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.mypackage.service.implementation.MyServiceImpl.myServiceMethod]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.453 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG c.b.a.c.b.s.i.MyServiceImpl - ----Entering into service method----
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.453 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG c.b.a.c.b.d.i.MyDaoImpl - ----Entering into DAO method----
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.454 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@fc93a7] for key [org.spring
framework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@41b972] bound to thread [qtp10408676-64]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.483 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.engine.spi.IdentifierValue - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.483 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Transient instance of: org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.487 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener - Saving transient instance
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.502 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: component[column1]{column1=valueOfColumn1}, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.536 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Saving [org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity#component[column1]{column1=valueOfColumn1}]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.559 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding an EntityInsertAction for [org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity] object
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.560 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity#(column1=valueOfColumn1)]]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.560 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG c.b.a.c.b.d.i.MyDaoImpl - ----Leaving from DAO method----
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG c.b.a.c.b.s.i.MyServiceImpl - ----Leaving from service method----
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.mypackage.service.implementation.MyServiceImpl.myServiceMethod]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.584 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@9d02de]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.585 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.585 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#beforeCompletionCallback
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.585 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - SessionImpl#beforeTransactionCompletion()
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.585 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Automatically flushing session
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.585 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing session
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.586 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.586 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.587 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.587 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.587 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.588 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing unreferenced collections
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.588 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.589 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.589 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.591 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.592 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity{column1 = valueOfColumn1, column2 = valueOfColumn2, column3 = valueOfColumn3}
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.594 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Executing flush
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.601 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.v.i.m.a.BeanMetaDataImpl - Members of the default group sequence for bean org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity are: [interface javax.validation.groups.Default].
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.602 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.v.i.m.a.BeanMetaDataImpl - Members of the default group sequence for bean java.lang.Object are: [interface javax.validation.groups.Default].
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.602 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Inserting entity: [org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity#component[column1]{column1=valueOfColumn1}]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.607 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.611 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.jmx.spi.JmxService]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.611 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.e.j.b.internal.BatchBuilderImpl - Building batch [size=1]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.650 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
     insert
     into
     MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
     (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
     values
        (?,?,?)
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.654 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@49b38d]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.714 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [org.mypackage.model.MyTableEntity#componentcomponent[column1]{column1=valueOfColumn1}]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.816 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [valueOfColumn1]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.816 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [valueOfColumn2]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.816 [qtp10408676-64] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [valueOfColumn3]
[STDOUT] 18:54:43.989 [qtp10408676-64] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
[STDOUT] java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE).
[STDOUT]
[STDOUT]        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
[STDOUT]        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
[STDOUT]        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

Expected :
I want to catch all the kind of DB exceptions in my service layer as I have a bunch of transactions to happen as UOW and If there is a failure I need to trnsalate that into my own exception by adding specfic reasons.

Actual :
Exceptions during DB operation are caught inside Controller method catch block

Comment: Are you sure this is the right syntax?

`public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService throws MyDefinedException`

Comment: @Angshuman, Sorry that was the typo. I edited now.

Comment: can you try catching javax.persistence.RollbackException at service layer?

Comment: @Angshuman, sure I ll try this and post you the result

Comment: @Angshuman,I tried by adding javax.persistence.RollbackException catch block next to EntityExistsException at Service layer. I still see DataIntegrityViolationException is caught inside catch block of Generic Exception at Contoller. No exception is caught at Service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create/update won't be committed until it returns from the @Transactional method. If the create/update is flushed to the database before that then the exceptionis caught  within the method, but in my case it's not being flushed until the commit.

```
@Repositary
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MYSCHEMA")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public String myDaoMethod(MyTableEntity myTableEntity) {
       LOGGER.debug("----Entering into DAO method----");
       entityManager.persist(myTableEntity);
       entityManager.flush(); // I can catch exceptions at Service after fluhing it.
       LOGGER.debug("----Leaving from DAO method----");
    }
}
```